# Image Radio Buttons flask_wtf

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

Trying to figure out how to use images as radio buttons using `flask_wtf` for Radiofield type of question in a form. I do not know how you actually set the images as the radio buttons.

I am aware of how to achieve this using just plain html but not with `flask_wtf`. I have my form setup correctly along with my `flask_wtf` class. I am aware that i have to loop through the subfields of the question in similar way to this:

```
{% for subfield in form.question1 %}
<tr>
<td>{{ subfield }}</td>
<td>{{ subfield.label }}</td> <!-- but how to set image??-->
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

This is the `flask_wtf` class. For demonstration purposes it has just the one `RadioField` question:

```
class questionform1(FlaskForm):
    question1 = RadioField('Question1', choices = [('a','a'),('b','b'), ('c','c'),('d','d')])
```

Using just HTML I would have done it this way:

```
<label>
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="a" id="q1a" required><img 
src="/static/img/image1.png">
</label>
```

I'm sure its possible somehow but there is a lack of information online about how to do it, any suggestions?